# How can I label my terms in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

in Mathematics when we define or describe terms we draw a rotated bracket above or underneath each term ,then we write whatever we want. I hope you get what I mean otherwise I have to include a photo. How can I produce these special rotated brackets? do they have specific names?

Comment: `\underbrace{mystuff}_{explanation}` and `\overbrace{mystuff}^{explanation}` perhaps ??? Both need math mode

Comment: `\underbrace{term}_{definition}` or  `\overbrace{term}^{definition}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a short example, without taking care about 'nice' output, with `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` and a special by `mathtools`: `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \underbrace{\ddot{x}^{i}}_{\text{Acceleration}} &= -\overbrace{\Gamma^{i}_{jk} \dot{x}^j \dot{x}^k}^{\text{Geodesic deviation}}\\
  \underbracket{\ddot{x}^{i}}_{\text{Acceleration}} &= -\overbracket{\Gamma^{i}_{jk} \dot{x}^j \dot{x}^k}^{\text{Geodesic deviation}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some `\mathclap` might be of use.

Comment: @BBM: Remove the `\text{}` command then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've tried to replace the word 'Acceleration' to a math symbol, say `J_{i}`, it says that there is a missing `$`. What should I do?

Comment: @BBM: See my previous comment.